# How to keep the mouse cursor fixed/focused at one position on the screen?

Tags: python

**PROBLEM :**

I would like to keep my mouse cursor fixed at a position and when I try to move my mouse it will automatically return to the fixed position. It's as if it stays focused on a particular position, let's say 80% of the screen (I said 80% because I want it to do the same thing on all types of screens, not just mine, so that if there is a bigger screen it will also be 80%, a bit like relx=0.8 instead of x=...)

**CODE :**

```
  screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

  target_x = int(screen_width * 0.8)
  target_y = int(screen_height * 0.8)


  pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
  current_x, current_y = pyautogui.position()


  if current_x == target_x and current_y == target_y:
         #do nothing no need to move the cursor right here because the position is reached
         

 


  pyautogui.moveTo(target_x, target_y)
```

I tried to put the whole thing in a `while True` loop but it will keep moving 80% I want it to stop or focus without moving when the fixed position is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use pynput.** (`pip install pynput`)

```
import pynput
```

Have the mouse move to your desired location, then:

```
mouse_listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(suppress=True)
mouse_listener.start()
```

To stop it: `mouse_listener.stop()`

Comment: Thanks but does it focus a position ? Like even if you move your move it will remain or return to the position your looking for (80% of the screen in my case) ???

Comment: @Meme410 This locks the mouse in place. I'm guessing that's what you want by "focus a position."